# How can I find maximum power transfer using Thevenin equivalent

Tags: basic, thevenin

[image]

As I understand it, should maximum power transfer be when $$ R_L=R_{th} $$ then $$ P_L= P_{L(max)} $$

So that this should do the trick:

$$ P_{L}=\frac{V_{th} ^2}{R_{th}} $$

But it seems that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple error in your reasoning.  When the load resistance is equal to the Thevenin resistance, the voltage across the load is precisely 1/2 the Thevenin voltage.

Thus,

\$P_{L,max} = \dfrac{V^2_{th}}{4R_{th}} \$

Your calculation would be correct if the entire Thevenin voltage appeared across the load but that isn't the case.

Comment: I see, that explains a lot.